# Why isn't Rancho Soldano's ruler a Soldano?

Tags: campaign-settings, 7th-sea

In 7th Sea's Castille source-book, each *Rancho* belongs to one of the most prominent families, and is ruled by one of its members, except for Rancho Soldano which is ruled by *Don Diego Ruiz de Ontiveros*, meaning he's son to Doña Ruiz and Don Ontiveros, but not to any Soldano (at least not close enough to carry his/her name).

I'm I missing something? I couldn't find any clues in the family descriptions as to why this is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still searching for a source, but following the nomenclature, it is entirely possible that the Soldano bloodline derives from his paternal grandmother.  If he is son of Don [given] Soldano de Ontiveros (del Soldano) that gives him the bloodline.  To be edited when I find sources, although I don't have access to any novels or other canon as of this post.

Comment: I didn't know there were 7th Sea novels out there, are they?

Comment: I know there was cannon plot derived from the card games the way they still do with L5R but they've since yanked the site for me to see what literature is out there.